# Do this with a single SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like that:

[image]

The rows are sorted by CLNDR_DATE DESC.

I need to find a CLNDR_DATE that corresponds to the highlighted row, in other words:
Find the topmost group of rows WHERE EFFECTIVE_DATE IS NOT NULL,
and return the CLNR_DATE of a last row of that group.

Normally I would open a cursor and cycle from top to bottom until I find a NULL in EFFECTIVE_DATE. Then I would know that the date I am looking for is CLNDR_DATE, obtained at the previous step.

However, I wonder if the same can be achieved with a single SQL?

Comment: What you are asking doesn't seem to be too bad, but can you clarify a little - are you saying that you need it to grab the earliest record from the table after the last null in effective_date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Warning: Not a DBA by any means. ;)

But, a quick, untested stab at it:

```
SELECT min(CLNDR_DATE) FROM [TABLE]
WHERE (EFFECTIVE_DATE IS NOT NULL)
  AND (CLNDR_DATE > (
    SELECT max(CLNDR_DATE) FROM [TABLE] WHERE EFFECTIVE_DATE IS NULL
  ))
```

Assuming you want the **first** CLNDR_DATE **with** EFFECTIVE_DATE after the **last without**.

If you want the **first with** after the **first without**, change the subquery to use min() instead of max().

Answer (score 1):

Using Oracle's analytic function (untested)

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    clndr_date, 
    effective_date, 
    lag(clndr_date, 1, null) over (order by clndr_date desc) prev_clndr_date
  from table
)
where effective_date is null
```

The `lag(clndr_date, 1, null) over (order by clndr_date desc)` returns the previous clndr_date, or use null if this is the first row.

(edit: fixed order)

Comment: over (order by clndr_date DESC)
does the job.

But yes, too slow :-(

Comment: The advantage of this is that it will show you all the gaps, not just the latest, this may or may not be what the OP wants, most likely not by the look of it.

Answer (score 0):

The first result from this recordset is what you're looking for.  Depending on your Database, you may be able to only return this row by using LIMIT, or TOP

```
SELECT CLNDR_DATE 
FROM TABLE
WHERE CLNDR_DATE > (SELECT MAX(CLNDR_DATE)
                    FROM TABLE 
                    WHERE EFFECTIVE_DATE IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY CLNDR_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Oracle environment you can use analytical functions (http://www.orafaq.com/node/55), which are very powerful tools to do kind of queries you asking for.

Using standard SQL I think it is impossible, but maybe some SQL gurus will show up some nice solution.